# How to return serializer to bulk create

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model which saves some files to db. When I upload the nested zip file (zip files inside main zip) I need to create an object for every file inside and return created objects in the serializer. But sometimes file can be just one file.

**models.py**

```
class CampaignManagerCreativeAsset(models.Model):
    asset_file = models.FileField(
        validators=[validate_file_extension], storage=AssetsMediaStorage()
    )
    mimetype = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

**helpers.py**

```
def _check_for_nested_zip(zip_file):
    all_zip = list()
    for file in zip_file.namelist():
        if file.lower().endswith('.zip'):
            all_zip.append(True)
        else:
            all_zip.append(False)
    return all_zip


def process_zip_file(file_object):
    with ZipFile(file_object, 'r') as zip_file:
        all_zip = _check_for_nested_zip(zip_file)
        if all(all_zip):
            files_to_create = list()
            files_content = {name: zip_file.read(name) for name in zip_file.namelist()}
            for filename, content in files_content.items():
                file = SimpleUploadedFile.from_dict(
                    {
                        'content': content,
                        'filename': filename,
                        'content-type': 'application/zip',
                    }
                )
                files_to_create.append(file)
            return files_to_create
        return file_object
```

**views.py**

```
class CreativeAssetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.CreativeAssetSerializer
    filter_fields = '__all__'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.CampaignManagerCreativeAsset.objects.all()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CreativeAssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CampaignManagerCreativeAsset
        fields = (
            'id',
            'external_creative_asset_id',
            'asset_file',
            'settings',
            'mimetype',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'external_creative_asset_id', 'mimetype')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        asset_file = validated_data.get('asset_file')
        settings = validated_data.get('settings')
        mimetype = helpers.get_mimetypes_type(asset_file.name)
        instances = list()

        if mimetype == 'application/zip':
            files_to_create = helpers.process_zip_file(asset_file)
            if not isinstance(files_to_create, list):
                instances.append(models.CampaignManagerCreativeAsset(**validated_data))
            else:
                for file in files_to_create:
                    instances.append(
                        models.CampaignManagerCreativeAsset(
                            asset_file=file, settings=settings
                        )
                    )
        return models.CampaignManagerCreativeAsset.objects.bulk_create(instances)
```

But I am getting error

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `asset_file` on serializer `CreativeAssetSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `list` instance.
Original exception text was: 'list' object has no attribute 'asset_file'.
```

How I can make this serializer to show list of created object after creating them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `return models.CampaignManagerCreativeAsset.objects.bulk_create(instances)`

The `rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer.create` method is supposed to return a single object and not a list of objects. Thus the error,

> "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `asset_file`.......... on the `list` instance".

Because it expected a single instance of `CampaignManagerCreativeAsset` model but got `list` instead.

You should instead use the `serializers.ListSerializer` to customize multiple creation as given in [DRF's docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create).